# The meaning of "view"

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, dictionaries

> One in four of those questioned said they did not know nor had any view on the matter.

What does *view* mean in the above sentence? Does it match the first sense or the second one in [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/view_1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It matches the first meaning in Oxford, if the writer is trying to imply that they had no particular thoughts or opinions about the subject.

The word **View** in this question refers to Opinion. The clue is to verify by substituting with the meaning and see if it makes sense

> One in four of those questioned said [*that*] they did not know nor have any **opinion** on the matter.

This is common usage.

However, if the intended meaning was **Understanding**, replacing it in the sentence would not make sense, as you will find below:

> One in four of those questioned said [*that*] they did not know nor have any **understanding** on the matter.

It ought to be understanding **of** the matter, rather than **on**.

Cheers!